# Java Cucumber custom object type arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-junit

I'm new to cucumber and i need to use it to implement tests for my java app. Among my tests, **i need to test a POST request webservice having an entity body (a custom object)**, so i thought i should send this body from my feature scenario to its implementation. I looked around and i saw that this is how you send a list of a custom object :

```
  Scenario: Some scenario
    Given something
      |filed1    |filed2     |filed3   |
      |value1    |value2     |value3   |
      |value1    |value2     |value3   |
   ......
```

And its implementation:

```
    @Given("^something:$")
    public void something(List<MyObject> arg1) {
       ......... Using the list        
    }
```

It actualy gives the list even without a mapper, but as i said in my case for the post request body, i only need to send one object not a list, something like that: **(don't know how to right the feature yet)**

```
    @Given("^something:$")
    public void something(MyObject arg1) {
       .........Using the object
    }
```

I tried multiple ways but can't seem to find the right one, can anyone give me a hand or a hint. And also tell me if i'm thinking with the right logic cauze if something works doesn't mean it's a good practice. Thanx in advance

Comment: Have you tried a table with a header and just one row?

Comment: @mpkorstanje yes, first thing i tried, but the implementation method crushes saying it expects an object and found a list

Comment: Which version of Cucumber do you have?

Comment: @mpkorstanje cucumber 1.2.5 and junit 4.12

Comment: Then I don't think that version can do single items. You have to use `.get(0)` to get it from the list.

Comment: I kinda try to avoid that cauze it's not professional but thanx

Comment: Check https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable

Comment: That's for Cucumber v4/5.